# Adding another label to a group of columns in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, label, data-manipulation

I want my matrix to look somewhat like this:

```
       Group 1       Group2      1-2
     col1   col2   col3   col4   col5
row1  .      .       .      .      .

row2  .      .       .      .      .

row3  .      .       .      .      .
```

I used `colnames()/rownames()` to get all of those names as I want, but I can't figure out how to add the `Group 1`, `Group 2` and `1-2` labels over the column names to indicate the data is from the same group.

Comment: R matrices can only have one set of headers. Are you trying to format this for some sort of report? There are packages for producing tables for printing, but are far as actually storing the data in R, it's not optimized for formatting. What problem are you really trying to solve here?

Comment: Yeah this is for a thesis I'm writing. So if the final table would look like this, that would be enough. Can you recommend a package for producing tables for printing?

Comment: It's unlikely that one would include raw R console output in a thesis. Here's a thread with suggestions for creating "pretty" tables:https://community.rstudio.com/t/output-nice-looking-formatted-tables/1084/9

Comment: Cool, I'll look into it. Thank you!